# C++ Ofstream a new line

Tags: c++, newline, ofstream

I am trying to do a new line in a ofstream, but it does not work. Everything is written on the same line in OUTPUT.txt

```
std::ofstream output;
output.open("OUTPUT.TXT");
output << "sometext" << "\r\n" << "sometext" << "\r\n" << "sometext";
output.close();
```

I also tried

```
output << "sometext" << std::endl << "sometext" << std::endl << "sometext";
```

and

```
output << "sometext" << "\n" << "sometext" << "\n" << "sometext";
```

and

```
output << "sometext" << '\n' << "sometext" << '\n' << "sometext";
```

Everything was written on the same line, no new lines... Am I missing something?

Comment: on Windows 7, using notepad.exe to read the output file

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using cygwin's g++, it [had some issues converting the "\n" to windows-style CRLF under some settings](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-10/msg00597.html), I tried a simple version of your snippet and it worked fine. Try opening in another text editor and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Probably. You're reading a different copy of the file than the one your program is writing to.  Delete the file, then run your program.

Comment: thats why I did... this is not the problem, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this I find it best to look at the file in a hex editor rather than a text editor that can have its own ideas on how to render text, it also can be good for finding pesky non-printable characters that can trip you up.

You didn't say what platform you are working on, but if you are on windows I would recommend using [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/).

If you are on Windows, you will see something like this:

```
Offset(h) 00       04       08       0C       10       14       18       1C

00000000  736F6D65 74657874 0D0A736F 6D657465 78740D0A 736F6D65 74657874 0D0A      sometext..sometext..sometext..
```

The hex sequence `0D0A` is the `\n` character on Windows in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
output.open("OUTPUT.TXT", ios::out);
```

Remind you that `ios::binary` cannot be used.