# C++ ofstream line break

Tags: c++, ofstream, line-breaks

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream ifile ("input.dat", ios::in);
    ofstream ofile ("output.dat",ios::out);

    int num;
    ifile >> num;
    ofile << num;
    ofile << endl;
    ofile << "Did we go to new line?";
    ofile << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, everything in output.dat is on the same line. How can I resolve this?

Thanks!

EDIT: I was using Windows to see the files and Linux to compile. This is why I was running into this issue. Using `cat output.dat` on the Linux side to see the file contents would have revealed that Windows vs. Linux line breaks are different at the time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Ofstream a new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352283/c-ofstream-a-new-line)

Comment: [Inconceivable](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-b7RmmMJeo). Are you *sure* output.dat has only one line? How are you checking? Also, what operating system and compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using windows and notepad to check the output file.

Comment: +1 for compilable example. I just compiled and ran this using VS2010 and newlines appeared correctly (my "input.dat" contained "4\n"). What is your compiler?

Comment: Our compile command is g++ -Wall source.cpp -o test
I'm assuming i'm using a compiler named g++?

Comment: For reference... where are you running `g++`? And where do you run the program? On a linux system? On a windows system using cygwin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::endl already inserts a linebreak, so you have linebreaks in your file. I assume you are generating your file on a LF system (Linux or other UNIX-like) and viewing it on a CRLF system. In this case, your linebreak won't show in the text editor as a linebreak. `unix2dos` is your friend.

Comment: I am using windows and notepad to check the output file.

Comment: Even if he generates under Unix and reads under Windows, most editors will display it correctly.  If that's his problem, the correct solution is to use a different editor; a true Windows program will output CRLF, but be agnostic for input (just as a true Windows program will output `\` as a path separator, but accept both `\` and `/`).

Comment: @Pirate43 Notepad is useless.  Try anything else (even `type filename` from a console window).

Comment: If using Cygwin to run gcc under Windows, there is an install option to have either Windows or Unix compatible text files.

Comment: @James Kanze true, but it's only for a small class assignment and it's easy to use.

Answer (score 7):

Replace `std::endl` with `"\r\n"` to get CRLF instead of just LF.

Comment: I'd recommend against this.  Except that if you're writing files under Unix, and you want Windows line endings, there's not much alternative.  (I wonder if anyone has implemented a `filebuf` which takes an additional formatting option, to specify the line ending convention that should be used for output.)

Comment: @JamesKanze : indeed, I couldn't agree more, but it seems that that is what happens here. Working with `filebuf` is better, and I would love to see it here.

Comment: @JamesKanze by the way I doubt if our friend here, can go to that extent, and that he is having such a broad range of applications to have his code working on that he should try `filebuf`.

Comment: @g24l I wasn't recommending that the OP write a new `filebuf`:-).  I was expressing a sort of a wish that some implementer would extend his `filebuf` in such a fashion.  (It would be nice under Linux if I had a `filebuf` option to convert the CRLF into a single `'\n'` as well.  But since `'\r'` is white space, and you always want to allow trailing white space, it's less of a problem.)

Comment: @Pablo @JamesKanze Late to the game, but implementing a `filebuf` is overkill.  After all, `std::endl` is a stream manipulator. Similarly, a custom ostream manipulator would take far less effort and be far less complicated.