# File Append In Such A Way That It Ends Line After Each Save C++

Tags: c++, append, file-handling

```
fstream file("afile.txt" , ios :: out | ios:: in | ios :: app);
if(!file.is_open())
{
    cout << "Error Loading File!";
}
else
{
    // cout << " File Created ";
}

for(i = 0 ; i < gameplayed ; i ++)
{

file <<name << " Won $"  << prize << " And Answered " << questions << " Questions" << "\n";

}
file.seekg(0);
string line;
while(file.good())
{

    getline(file,line);
    cout <<  line  ;
}
```

So basically the codes works perfectly and doesn't overwrite, but it just starts right after like

"Player Won $2000 Dollars And Answered 6 Questions Plater2 Won $2000 Dollars And Answered 6 Questions"

I want is To Appear Like
With a line break and not after it

Comment: You are writing each line without a line break between them, so...

Answer (score 2):

[This will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705923/c-ofstream-line-break)

> Replace std::endl with "\r\n" to get CRLF instead of just LF.

Comment: ooh, it was that simple

Comment: haha, appreciated man,!!

Comment: you could mention the difference between line feeds in linux and windows

Answer (score 1):

Your output *does* have line breaks.

However, it doesn't have carriage returns.

If you're reading the file on Windows, in an app that makes a distinction, you won't "see" the break.

You may wish to consider writing `\r\n` instead, which is the standard line ending sequence on Windows.